# PySCF: How to do CCSD calculations from an FCIDUMP file in HDF5 format?

Tags: python, high-performance-computing, pyscf, integrals, fcidump

Recently my question: [Why does CCSD work, but not CCSD(T), after reading an FCIDUMP in PySCF?](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/10277/5) lead to a [bug fix](https://github.com/pyscf/pyscf/pull/1580) that allows users to do CCSD(T) calculations from an FCIDUMP file in PySCF. **That was with the FCIDUMP file being in ASCII format though!**

When the FCIDUMP file is in ASCII format, it's easy to create an "SCF object" from  the dump file:

```
mf = pyscf.tools.fcidump.to_scf(name+'.fcidump', molpro_orbsym=False, mf=None)
mf.run()
```

That object is what's required to do CCSD calculations:

```
mcc = cc.CCSD(mf)
e = mcc.kernel()
```

However the function that "loads" an FCIDUMP file in HDF5 format gives an `eri` object instead of an `scf` object:

```
eri = ao2mo.load(name+'.fcidump.h5',dataname='dummy_label')
```

### Attempting to do CCSD from only the ERI object

If I were just to replace the above `mf` with `eri` as in the line below:

```
mcc = cc.CCSD(eri)
```

then it will trigger the `convert_to_rhf` function in `pyscf/scf/addons.py` which will crash at `assert (isinstance(mf, hf.SCF))` presumably because `eri` is ***not*** an instance of an `hf.SCF` object.

By simply doing:

```
mcc = cc.CCSD()
```

there will be a complaint about the required `mf` input being missing. If we do:

```
mcc = pyscf.cc.ccsd.kernel(eris=eri, callback=None)
```

there will be an error because `cc.ccsd.kernel()` requries a `mycc` object as an input argument. The following gets us closer:

```
mcc = pyscf.cc.ccsd.kernel(0,eris=eri, verbose=9,callback=None)
```

but ends in `pyscf/cc/ccsd.py` at `mycc.get_init_guess(eris)` presumably because the integer `0` doesn't contain information about the initial guess for the CCSD calculation:

```
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'get_init_guess'
```

In most programs, asking for a CCSD calculation automatically triggers an MP2 calculation so that there's a decent initial guess for the CCSD, and I'm sure that's also happening in PySCF if I do `cc.CCSD(mf)`, but it seems that if we run `pyscf.cc.ccsd.kernel()` instead (due to not having an `mf` object), then we need to do explicitly tell the program to do an MP2 calcualtion first. The brings us to the question:

### Attempting to do MP2 from only the ERI object

Running `mf.MP2().run()` requires an `mf` object. The following:

```
eri.MP2().run(verbose=9)
```

won't work because `eri` is a `load` object and doesn't have an `mp2` attribute:

```
AttributeError: 'load' object has no attribute 'MP2'
```

In fact `pyscf.ci.cisd.CISD()` would also complain about not having an `mf` object.

### Attempting to get an SCF object from an ERI object

As long as we can get an `mf` object from the `eri`, we can do CISD, MP2, CCSD and much more. Attempting to create the `mf` object from the FCIDUMP in the way that we did when the FCIDUMP was in ASCII format:

```
mf = pyscf.tools.fcidump.to_scf(name+'.fcidump.h5', molpro_orbsym=False, mf=None)
```

just leads to a complaint which seems to be about the FCIDUMP file not being in ASCII format:

```
python3.8/codecs.py", line 322, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x89 in position 0: invalid start byte
```

There's [not much documentation for `pyscf.tools.fcidump.to_scf()`](https://pyscf.org/pyscf_api_docs/pyscf.tools.html) but [the source code](https://pyscf.org/_modules/pyscf/tools/fcidump.html#to_scf) suggests that it will only work if the FCIDUMP file is in ASCII format. Perhaps it can be hacked to go into the HDF5 file and fetch the integrals, but I would think that since PySCF has the capability to `load` the integrals with `ao2mo.load()`, it would have the ability to ***use*** loaded integrals, meaning that there's already a way to get the `mf` object from an `eri` object.

I've also looked at `pyscf.tools.fcidump.scf_from_fcidump()` but it seems to require the user to already have an `mf` object. Also in `pyscf/tools/fcidump.py` there are the `from_mo()` and `from_integrals()`, but they are for writing FCIDUMP files, not loading them.

### Question

My question was how to do CCSD from an FCIDUMP file in HDF5 format. Based on the above troubleshooting, I've discovered that it boils down to converting the `eri` object obtained from the FCIDUMP.h5 file into an `scf` object, which I don't know how to do!

The following script will create the `FCIDUMP.h5` file (only about 11 kB since I used a STO-3G basis set) and then will load the FCIDUMP.h5 file into an `eri` object which is classified as a "load" object:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# Author: Nike Dattani, nike@hpqc.org

import pyscf
from pyscf import gto, scf, ao2mo, cc

mol = gto.Mole()
mol.atom = ''' O
               H  1  0.9576257
               H  1  0.9576257  2 104.51 '''
mol.unit = 'angstrom'
mol.basis = 'STO-3G'
mol.charge = 0
mol.spin = 0
mol.verbose = 9
mol.symmetry = True
mol.symmetry_subgroup = 'C2v'
name = 'out'
#mol.output = name+'.txt' # only worked up to end of SCF (CC output went to stdout)
mol.build()

#####################
## Hartree-Fock:
#####################

mf = mol.RHF().set(chkfile = name + '.chk')
mf.kernel()

pyscf.ao2mo.kernel(mol, mf.mo_coeff, name+'.fcidump.h5', dataname='hdf5_group_name')
eri = ao2mo.load(name+'.fcidump.h5',dataname='dummy_label')
```

Running the above script will also give you an `mf` object, but the question is how to continue to post-HF calculations without using it at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for all these troubleshooting. As you noticed, `ao2mo.kernel`
does not give "an FCIDUMP file in HDF5 format", but only provides 2-electron integrals in MO basis. Similarly `ao2mo.load` only loads 2-e integrals. You will need more information, such as 1-e integrals, to re-create a `mf` object.

If the FCIDUMP file in HDF5 format, instead of ASCII, is desired, basically you can change the relevant functions in `tools/fcidump.py` to enable it. PySCF currently doesn't have a HDF5 counterpart for the FCIDUMP read/write functions. One reason is that there are no well-adopted standards to store the information in HDF5. Some programs may have their internal format, but this limits the transferability between programs. The text-based FCIDUMP format, on the other hand, has been adopted in the community for many years.

As a temporary solution, I wrote a script to allow write and read HDF5 in a similar fashion to how you treat FCIDUMP. Please feel free to use/modify/optimize. Eventually, such codes can be merged into PySCF.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import h5py, numpy
import pyscf
from pyscf import gto, scf, ao2mo, cc, tools
from pyscf.tools.fcidump import TOL, DEFAULT_FLOAT_FORMAT, MOLPRO_ORBSYM

#####################
## Redefine functions to enable HDF5 format (these functions mirror those in pyscf/tools/fcidump.py)
#####################

# Write some basic information to HDF5
def write_head(fout, nmo, nelec, ms=0, orbsym=None):
    if not isinstance(nelec, (int, numpy.number)):
        ms = abs(nelec[0] - nelec[1])
        nelec = nelec[0] + nelec[1]
    fout['norb'] = nmo
    fout['nelec'] = nelec
    fout['ms2'] = ms
    if orbsym is not None and len(orbsym) > 0:
        fout['orbsym'] = numpy.asarray(orbsym) 
    else:
        fout['orbsym'] = numpy.full(1, nmo) 
    fout['isym'] = 1

# Write 2-e integrals to HDF5
def write_eri(fout, eri, nmo, tol=TOL, float_format=DEFAULT_FLOAT_FORMAT):
    if eri.size == nmo**4:
        eri = ao2mo.restore(8, eri, nmo)
    fout.create_dataset('h2', data=eri)

# Write 1-e integrals to HDF5
def write_hcore(fout, h, nmo, tol=TOL, float_format=DEFAULT_FLOAT_FORMAT):
    h = h.reshape(nmo,nmo)
    fout.create_dataset('h1', data=h)

# Convert the given 1-electron and 2-electron integrals to HDF5 format
def hdf5_from_integrals(filename, h1e, h2e, nmo, nelec, nuc=0, ms=0, orbsym=None,
                        tol=TOL, float_format=DEFAULT_FLOAT_FORMAT):
    with h5py.File(filename, 'w') as fout:
        write_head(fout, nmo, nelec, ms, orbsym)
        write_eri(fout, h2e, nmo, tol=tol, float_format=float_format)
        write_hcore(fout, h1e, nmo, tol=tol, float_format=float_format)
        fout['nuc'] = nuc

# Use the Hamiltonians stored in HDF5 format to build an SCF object
def hdf5_to_scf(filename, molpro_orbsym=MOLPRO_ORBSYM, mf=None, **kwargs):
    with h5py.File(filename, 'r') as f:
        mol = gto.M()
        mol.nelectron = int(f['nelec'][()])
        mol.spin = int(f['ms2'][()])
        norb = mol.nao = int(f['norb'][()])
        nuc = f['nuc'][()]
        mol.energy_nuc = lambda *args: nuc 
        mol.incore_anyway = True
        if 'orbsym' in f.keys():
            mol.symmetry = True
            mol.groupname = 'N/A'
            orbsym = f['orbsym'][()]
            mol.irrep_id = list(set(orbsym))
            mol.irrep_name = [('IR%d' % ir) for ir in mol.irrep_id]
            so = numpy.eye(norb)
            mol.symm_orb = []
            for ir in mol.irrep_id:
                mol.symm_orb.append(so[:,orbsym==ir])

        if mf is None:
            mf = mol.RHF(**kwargs)
        else:
            mf.mol = mol
        h1 = f['h1'][()]
        mf.get_hcore = lambda *args: h1
        mf.get_ovlp = lambda *args: numpy.eye(norb)
        
        norb_pair = norb * (norb+1) // 2
        h2e = f['h2'][()]
        mf._eri = h2e[numpy.tril_indices(norb_pair)]

    return mf


#####################
## Input starts here
#####################

mol = gto.Mole()
mol.atom = ''' O
               H  1  0.9576257
               H  1  0.9576257  2 104.51 '''
mol.unit = 'angstrom'
mol.basis = 'CC-PVTZ'
mol.charge = 0
mol.spin = 0
mol.verbose = 9
mol.symmetry = True
mol.symmetry_subgroup = 'C2v'
name = 'out'
mol.build()

#####################
## Hartree-Fock:
#####################

mf = mol.RHF().set(chkfile = name + '.chk')
mf.kernel()

# Replace two functions in tools/fcidump.py if you want to store information as HDF5
store_as_h5 = True
if store_as_h5: 
    from pyscf.tools import fcidump
    fcidump.from_integrals = hdf5_from_integrals
    fcidump.to_scf = hdf5_to_scf
    ext = 'h5'
else:
    ext = 'fcidump'

tools.fcidump.from_chkfile(f'{name}.{ext}',name+'.chk', tol=1e-18, float_format=' %.16g', molpro_orbsym=False, orbsym=None)
mf = tools.fcidump.to_scf(f'{name}.{ext}', molpro_orbsym=False, mf=None)
mf.kernel()

#####################
## post-Hartree-Fock:
#####################

mcc = cc.CCSD(mf).set(frozen=1,verbose=9)
e = mcc.kernel()
et = mcc.ccsd_t()
```